# Using random user agent vs proxy in scraping?

Tags: proxy, web-scraping, user-agent

I am recently working on web scraping.
I found that we can use proxy or random user agents to stay away from anti - scraping detection's.

Is there any difference between proxy and random user agents?

Because I got confused when I understood that both are used to hide the original client request identity.

If m understanding is wrong please let me know

Answer (score 2):

Useragent and proxy are totally different concepts

1) **Useragents** : The useragent will be sent to the targeted website through headers

When I send a request to stackoverflow, my useragent is :

User-Agent: **Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0**

It says I'm using mozilla and linux + other infos. Everyone using same browser (firefox 5.0) on linux will have the same useragent.

This library will help you find the most common useragents used on the web so that your useragent looks anonymous : https://github.com/Lobstrio/shadow-useragent

2) **Proxy**

A proxy will let you hide your ip adress behind a proxy. The website you target will receive the ip address of the proxy rather than yours. If you ip get blocked by the website, then using a proxy would normally unlock the website.

There can be many reasons why you can be blocked during scraping but rotating ip and useragents can be effective in some cases